# understanding ifstream objects and reading from files

Tags: c++

I'm just learning and practicing the basics of ifstream objects and tried to write a small program that will read a .txt file and then display what is read. I can't tell what I need to change, but i do know that there might be something wrong with how I'm specifying the path because. When I run the program, it doesn't seem like it can open the file. the friends.txt file I made is in the path I specified. In the .txt file, there are 3 names which are written on 3 consecutive lines (after typing one name, I pressed enter to write another name on a new line).

I tried checking to see if made any typos on the folder names in the path and made sure to correct any I found.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    string name;

    inputfile.open("C:\\Users\\Dox\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Practice\\Practice\\friends.txt");
    cout << "Reading data from the file.\n";

    if (!inputfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "error opening file" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        inputfile >> name;
        cout << name << endl;
        inputfile >> name;
        cout << name << endl;
        inputfile >> name;
        cout << name << endl;
    }
    inputfile.close();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When running the code, the error message I made displays.

Comment: I suggest you check your file permissions. I just ran your code verbatim, save for changing the file path to C:\\temp\\friends.txt, and it worked OK. You could always add some deeper error checking so you get a more useful message.

Comment: Well, I checked the file permissions and saw that I had full control over the .txt file, but I'm still not sure where to go from here. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I've been racking my brain since yesterday and finally learned my problem was coming from how I was naming the .txt file. I was literally typing "friends.txt" into the file name section in the save as window of notepad when I was creating the .txt file. Once I just saved the .txt file as "friends", everything started reading from the file just fine. I realized this when I observed how an ostream object was automatically creating files.

Comment: So you original file was actually called friends.txt.txt? Yay for Windows hiding file extension by default!